# proof of conditional expectation given n i.i.d. random variables

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, economics

This is another question from my self-study of Hayashi's Econometrics.

How do we show in mathematical proof that given:

$X = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}' \\x_{2}' \\\vdots \\x_{n}'\end{bmatrix}$ where $x_{i} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{i1} \\x_{i2} \\\vdots \\x_{ik} \end{bmatrix} $

and
$y = \begin{bmatrix}y_{1}' \\y_{2}' \\\vdots \\y_{n}'\end{bmatrix}$

If $(y, X)$ is a random sample, where $(y_{i},x_{i})$ and $(y_{j},x_{j})$ are i.i.d. for $i\neq j$, and $\epsilon_{i}$ is a function of $(y_{i},x_{i})$, then the assumption:

$E[\epsilon_{i}|X]$ = $E[\epsilon_{i}|x_{i}]$

and

$E[\epsilon_{i}^2|X]$ = $E[\epsilon_{i}^2|x_{i}]$ ?

I mean it looks intuitively correct, but I checked the probability text and couldn't find a matching theorem corresponding to this.

The original text from the book Econometrics Hayashi is quoted:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you very much.

---

Update of the proof from my cousin:

$E[\epsilon_{i}|X]$ = $E[\epsilon_{i}|x_{i}]$

$E[\epsilon_{i}|x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots,x_{n}]
 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot f_{\epsilon_{i}|X}(\epsilon_{i}|x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots,x_{n})d\epsilon_{i}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot \dfrac{f(\epsilon_{i},x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots,x_{n})}{f(x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots,x_{n})} d\epsilon_{i}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot \dfrac{f(\epsilon_{i},x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots,x_{n})}{f(x_{1})f(x_{2}) \cdots f(x_{n})} d\epsilon_{i}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot \dfrac{f(\epsilon_{i},x_{i})f(x_{1})f(x_{2}) \cdots f(x_{n})}{f(x_{i})f(x_{1})f(x_{2}) \cdots f(x_{i-1})f(x_{i+1})f(x_{n})} d\epsilon_{i}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot \dfrac{f(\epsilon_{i},x_{i})}{f(x_{i})} d\epsilon_{i}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_{i} \cdot f(\epsilon_{i}|x_{i}) d\epsilon_{i}$

$= E[\epsilon_{i}|x_{i}]$

QED

I really appreciate the help from StackExchange Mathematics. This question is more related to econometrics in Cross Validation section. I post the same question there but got downvoted for no reason and was held on hold. Maybe my questions are naiive to some of you, but I really appreciate it your tolerance and kindness in helping me understand some of these theorems/proofs.

Comment: So, what do you not like about the proof from your cousin?

Comment: No, I like it very much. I don't think it's a good idea to answer my own question using my cousin's proof. So I updated the proof in the question with a long underline.

Comment: So there's nothing further to answer here? If so, the answer should be as an answer; you can post it as community wiki if it's not yours...

Comment: It's still possible to work on the second equation, $E[\epsilon_{i}^2 |X] = E[\epsilon_{i}^2 |x_{i}] $. By the way what does it mean community wiki?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts